# Not showing a image before the start of the JW Player, if URL contains the string base64

Tags: javascript, base64, jwplayer, jwplayer6

Does not show a image JW Player.

URL of the image to be in base64 encoded string.

As shown in the following picture options **image**.

```
    var file = '/videos/file.mp4',  
    image = 'data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJABAg...JP1okrOwH//2Q==';

    jwplayer('player').setup({          
         flashplayer: '/jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf',     
         html5player: '/jwplayer/jwplayer.html5.js',                             
         file: file,     
         image: image 
    });
```

As before the start of the JW Player to show a image???

Comment: Do you have a link? Not totally sure that is a supported set up though.

Comment: Links only in this form, the image is be on another server.
Obtained via php to save the image on your server and then show it. Javascript means you can not convert base64, that image shows in the JW Player.

Comment: I mean a link to your player embed to where it isn't working so I can inspect it.

Answer (score 1):

The setup complete code of the player.

```
<script src="/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>     
<script>    
var image = "data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJABAg...JP1okrOwH//2Q==",
/* other variables */

onJWPlayerLoad(file, tracksFile, width, height, autostart, image, rtmp);

function onJWPlayerLoad(file, tracksFile, width, height, autostart, image) {
    jwplayer.key = 'key';

    jwplayer('player').setup({
        flashplayer: '/jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf',
        html5player: '/jwplayer/jwplayer.html5.js',                        

        file: file,

        controls: true,

        tracks: [{ 
            file: tracksFile,
            kind: 'thumbnails'
        }],

        width: width,
        height: height,

        autostart: autostart,

        image: image            
    });           

}
</script>
```

Comment: Ethan wants you to give us a link to your site, rather than posting code. He needs that for debugging.

Comment: Exactly, that is what I meant.